# can tags be replacement of taxonomy?

Tags: usability, tagging, taxonomy

My Question is around usability. In most of the sites i have seen and developed i see taxonomy as a way a user would find something he is looking for in the site. But quite recently i have seen the concept of tagging. Where products services questions are tagged and can be found with the tagname. Is tagging an alternative to taxonomy or they should work together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I'd say that like most things, it depends on what kind of information you're trying to organize.**

For example, here on Stack Overflow, there isn't really a rigid hierarchy by which to sort the questions. They're much more organic in the sense that they can span multiple, and even unrelated, disciplines or fields and create a whole host of dynamic connections. For organizing this type of information, I think tags are an appropriate replacement for traditional, hierarchical taxonification. The decentralized, dehierarchized nature of tagging dovetails perfectly with the general organization of the site's content, *especially* when the site's users/community is encouraged to participate in cataloguing and organizing the information. Many blogs and social networking sites like [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) organize their content with a series of tags as well.

Conversely, if you're trying to sell products or provide technical support, you'll probably find that tagging is not a suitable replacement for traditional taxonomic organization. If you're familiar with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com), which provides online documentation for developers in the Microsoft ecosystem, you'll observe that most of its content is organized into a natural hierarchy by technology/language, feature, sub-feature, etc. If you want to buy a computer from [Dell](http://www.dell.com/), you start by narrowing down your choices: do you want a desktop, notebook, or tablet? Do you want a performance-oriented notebook, a desktop-replacement notebook, or an ultra-portable? Etc. Of course, that doesn't mean that you shouldn't consider implementing tags as an *alternative* way for users to explore the information that you have available, but in the best of cases, they will work together.

Think about the type of content you plan to host on your site and consider the most natural way to organize that information. Your users will appreciate more than anything a site that is intuitive and where they feel it is easy to locate exactly what they're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen some Q/A sites which organize content into taxonomies. Like Computers>Languages>java>Multithreading. How does stackoverflow simple tagging system overscores that?

Comment: @sushil: I have seen that as well. I think that like Yahoo's old directory organization scheme that that's sort of the "old" way of doing things. Most of those sites' organizational schemes were designed before tagging was a well-known tactic, and I think usability and intuition suffers for it. Their content doesn't really fit all that well into a strict taxonomical system (what if I'm asking about debugging a multithreaded application remotely?). It works, but it isn't ideal. When designing a site now, I would try and pull from the best available concepts and trends. Tags are a great fit.

Comment: could u suggest ne some guiding principle, examples where i can say oh yes tags and not taxonomy fits here perefectly well. And some where i going without taxonomy can be a risk.

Answer (score 4):

That is an argument I always found interesting, and basically I reduce to this question:

**In order to found something, is better to have a hierarchical taxonomy or a flat tag-based taxonomy (maybe collaborative i.e. [Folksonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy)) ?**

Well, there's no unique answer, but, depending on the search context, sometimes the former is more convenient and sometimes the latter is.

The best thing would be to have both kind of taxonomies, but could be difficult to manage, in particular if contents are created by people and so the classification is up to them.

One solution could be have tags inheritance, like in [drupal taxonomy system](http://drupal.org/node/774892).

So for instance when you want to classify a picture of your dog, you just have to select the tag: `'dogs'` and automatically your picture will belong to tags: `'dogs' --> 'animals' --> 'living beings'` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This question is an issue related to the human thinking:

Sure it is better, if you can find something by a tagged word. If you dont know the word/tag perfectly, you are not able to find it. Others may have taged the thing you search for with a similar, but other tag. In this case a (binary) tag search will not give you the correct (or whole) awnser.

Anyway, there is a possibility to extract a taxonomy (as long as words/tags are related) out of tags. This concept (combined with a vecor-orientated-search) can be presented to the user and will help him to find what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'd just upvote [Cody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172439/can-tags-be-replacement-of-taxonomy/4172586#4172586) (I did), I would also like to add something:

The field of usability used to be within the realm of **ergonomics** before it grew up. So I think it is appropriate to refer to one of ergonomics' core principles.

> Every person has a unique set of dimensions, so there is no single set of “correct dimensions” for e.g. a chair. The best dimensions are **adjustable dimensions** that provide a reasonable range of variability.

It is possible to apply this principle to website navigation as well and **provide multiple ways of reaching the same content**, so that people with different habits can find stuff using the way they are most comfortable with.